# Auto-creating A records with kubernetes services

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53

I've got a kubernetes 1.6.2 cluster, and am creating a service like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: myns
  annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
      dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/internal: mydomain.com
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I'd expect this to create an internal ELB (which it does) but also set up an A record on the AWS Route53 hosted zone for mydomain.com as per https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/dns-controller (which it doesn't). Is there something I need to do to enable A record creation?

Comment: i am hitting the same scenario where i want to auto-create A records in Route53 for my loadbalancer service. Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

In route 53 create a type A record with `Alias Yes` prior to launching your cluster and Kurbernetes will audio update it with proper Alias Target which gets resolved to the correct IP upon app boot up when you issue

```
kubectl expose rs .....
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not work since dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/internal requires that you use NodePort, at least that's what's written in here https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1082

Update:

There's an open issue about this A-record. CNAME record can be created but A record is not yet working. Forgot the issue number but I think you can find it from kops github issues.